# Evaluating $\lim_{\text{Im}(z)\rightarrow \infty} \left [\frac{1}{(1+e^{\pi i z})^2}+\frac{1}{(1-e^{\pi i z})^2}\right ]$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am trying to evaluate $$\lim_{\text{Im}(z)\rightarrow \infty} \left [\frac{1}{(1+e^{\pi i z})^2}+\frac{1}{(1-e^{\pi i z})^2}\right ]$$

The answer I believe is $\frac{2}{\pi^2}$, as there is an example of this limit in *Ahlfors book* Pg. $272$ where he finds that 
$$\lim_{\text{Im}(z)\rightarrow \infty} 2\pi^2 \left [\frac{4}{(1+e^{\pi i z})^2}+\frac{4}{(1-e^{\pi i z})^2}\right ]=16$$
 However, he does not explain how he gets this.

This is my (incorrect if you take *Ahlfors* answer to be correct) try:

We have that $|e^{\pi i z}|=e^{-\pi \text{Im}(z)}$.

Therefore

$$\lvert 1+e^{\pi i z}\rvert=\lvert1+e^{\pi i \text{Re}(z)}\cdot e^{-\pi \text{Im}(z)}\rvert$$

$$=\lvert1+e^{-\pi \text{Im}(z)}[\cos(\pi \text{Re}(z))+i\sin(\pi \text{Re}(z)]\rvert$$

$$=\lvert1+e^{-\pi\text{Im}(z)}\cos(\pi \text{Re}(z))+ie^{-\pi\text{Im}(z)}\sin(\pi\text{Re}(z))\rvert$$

$$=(1+e^{-\pi\text{Im}(z)}\cos(\pi \text{Re}(z)))^2+(e^{-\pi\text{Im}(z)}\sin(\pi\text{Re}(z)))^2$$

$$=2+2e^{-\pi\text{Im}(z)}\cos(\pi \text{Re}(z))$$

And therefore when we square and take the limit we are left with 
$$\lim_{\text{Im}(z)\rightarrow \infty}\lvert1+e^{\pi i z}\rvert^2=4$$
And
$$\lim_{\text{Im}(z)\rightarrow \infty}\lvert1-e^{\pi i z}\rvert^2=4$$
Follows by the same logic.

Since $(1\pm e^{\pi iz})^2=|1\pm e^{\pi iz}|^2$ we have that the limit in question is $$\frac{1}{2}$$ However this does not agree with the answer extracted from *Ahlfors limit*. Can anyone help me see where I went wrong?

Comment: Can you find the limit $\lim_{\text{Im}(z)\to \infty}e^{i\pi z}=\lim_{y\to \infty}e^{i\pi x}e^{-\pi y}$?

Comment: I don't see anything resembling that limit near page 272 of my edition of Ahlfors' book. Can you give a section number?

Comment: It's in chapter 7 Section 3.5, he wants to find the order that the modular lambda function vanishes together with $e^{\pi i \tau}$. @Dr.MV Doesn't that limit equal zero provided that $x$ is finite?

Comment: @Dr.MV Won't that mean that the limit is equal to $2$? I'm guessing I am missing some intuition as to what Ahlfors means.

Comment: Ahlfors looks at $$2\pi^2 \biggl[ \frac{4e^{\pi i\tau}}{(1 + e^{\pi i\tau})^2} + \frac{4e^{\pi i\tau}}{(1 - e^{\pi i\tau})^2}\biggr].$$ That makes a significant difference.

Comment: However he multiples this by $e^{\pi i \tau}$ I believe. As the sum of the two leading terms equals what you have above and then he has $\lambda(\tau)e^{-\pi i \tau}\rightarrow 16$

Comment: "The sum of these terms is $$2\pi^2\left [\frac{4e^{\pi i\tau}}{(1+e^{\pi i\tau})^2}+\frac{4e^{\pi i\tau}}{(1-e^{\pi i \tau})^2}\right ]$$ and we conclude that $\lambda(\tau)e^{-\pi i\tau}\rightarrow 16$."

Comment: Ah, didn't read enough context. But $\lambda(\tau) = \frac{e_3 - e_2}{e_1 - e_2}$, and both $e_3 - e_2$ and $e_1 - e_2$ have a factor $\pi^2$ before the series, so upon division, that factor cancels. Thus you get no $\pi$ in your limit. Your limit evaluates to $2$ as soon as you see $\lim\limits_{\operatorname{Im} \tau \to +\infty} e^{\pi i\tau} = 0$.

Comment: Ah I see! perfect thank you